# FileSystemWatcher with threaded FIFO processing

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have single threaded C# console application that uses `FileSystemWatcher` to watch folder for new files.

My app sees a file being written, waits until it is released, then picks it up and processes it. At the same time it writes a rolling log to a text file:

> ```
> 2014-08-06 16:20:1.500 - Found file : C:\test1.pdf 
> 2014-08-06 16:20:1.510 - Waiting for file to become available 
> 2014-08-06 16:20:2.010 - Processing file 
> 2014-08-06 16:20:8.256 - Finished processing file: C:\test1.pdf 
> 2014-08-06 16:20:8.785 - File C:\test2.pdf found! 
>
> etc..etc..
> ```

The current method ensures the following:

1. Each file is processed in the order that `FileSystemWatcher` sees it.
2. The log file is written in a linear fashion, one file at a time.

Files created in the folder seem to be cached `FileSystemWatcher` until the current file has finished processing.
This works OK but I don't like the fact that `FileSystemWatcher` is caching it, it must have a buffer limit somewhere and files might drop of the end.

I think I need two threads:

1. `FileSystemWatcher` thread that sees the new files and passes to a 'Files to Process' collection.
2. File processing thread that sees there are items in the 'Files to Process' collection and processes them, FIFO style.

I started work on this and decided to use an `ObservableCollection` for the 'Files to Process' list, I thought I could hang methods off the `NotifyCollectionChangedAction` events but I am a bit stuck as to where to now put the thread.

My questions are:

1. Do I need two threads?
2. Is `ObservableCollection` the best object to use to manage the list of files to process?
3. Where do I put a second thread? I am guessing that I need a new thread each time a new file is added to the `ObservableCollection` but won't that trigger a thread for each file, then the log will be jumbled up with each file that is added to the collection?

The files that `FileSystemWatcher` pick up become `Document` objects.
Here is the code I have so far:

```c#
//Make the objects and set events
watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(AddDocument);
docsToProcess = new ObservableCollection<Document>();
docsToProcess.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(CollectionChanged);


//Called by FileSystemWatcher when it sees a new file
 void AddDocument(object source, FileSystemEventArgs f) 
        {
            Document doc = new Document(f.FullPath);
            docsToProcess.Add(doc);
        }

//Called when the collection changes       
 void CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.Action)
            {
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                    foreach (Document doc in e.NewItems)
                    {
                        log.Write("Found file : " + doc.FullPath);
                        ProcessDoc(doc);
                    }
                    break;

                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                    foreach (Document doc in e.OldItems)
                    {
                        log.Write("Finished Processing file : " + doc.FullPath);
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }   

//Called when a new document is added to the collection
 void ProcessDoc(Document doc)
        {
            //Do processing stuff to the document, also write to the log 
            //Then remove itself from the collection
            docsToProcess.Remove(doc);
        }
```

Comment: How exactly are you waiting for the file to become available?

Comment: @svick I wait by attempting to open the file exclusively, they are pdfs dropped onto an FTP server. If I cannot open I wait 30 seconds and try again.

Answer (score 8):

> Files created in the folder seem to be cached `FileSystemWatcher` until the current file has finished processing.

Not really cached, `FileSystemWatcher` just raises its events one at a time. So, until your event handler returns, you won't get another notification. And since you execute all your code in that event handler, that can take a very long time.

[The docs say this:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher)

> To avoid missing events, follow these guidelines:
>
> - […]
> - Keep your event handling code as short as possible.

So you shouldn't do it this way.

---

> Do I need two threads?

If you want to make reasonably sure you won't miss anything, yes, you need (at least) two threads.

> Is `ObservableCollection` the best object to use to manage the list of files to process?

In the current state, `ObservableCollection` doesn't make much sense, because there is no list, you will only ever have one item in the collection.

If you switched to two (or more) threads, `ObservableCollection` is still not a great choice, since it's not thread-safe.

> Where do I put a second thread? I am guessing that I need a new thread each time a new file is added to the `ObservableCollection` but won't that trigger a thread for each file, then the log will be jumbled up with each file that is added to the collection?

If you wanted to process each file in parallel, you would need more threads. To keep the log clean (and to perform any other operations that are not thread-safe), you should use [a lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx).

In any case, you shouldn't directly use `Thread`s. Instead, you should use `Task`s, or some higher-level constructs (see below for more), since they are more efficient and easier to work with.

But if you don't need parallelism, a single processing thread (i.e. two threads in total) is enough and it also means you don't need any locks (assuming only this thread writes to the log).

---

Some specific options on how you could implement this:

1. Use [`ActionBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684) from TPL Dataflow (requires .Net 4.5). This could be the simplest option, since it means you don't need to create any `Thread`s or `Task`s manually.

   In the event handler, you would call `Post()`, and the work would be handled by the delegate that you passed to `ActionBlock`'s constructor.

   `ActionBlock` can also work in parallel, if you set its [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.executiondataflowblockoptions.maxdegreeofparallelism).
2. Use [`BlockingCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312) and a `Task` with a loop.

   In the event handler, you would call `Add()`. You would then also create a `Task` (using `Task.Run()` or `Task.Factory.StartNew()`) with a `foreach` loop over [`GetConsumingEnumerable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186), that process the files.

   This will work best if there is only a single `Task`, which means it won't be parallel.
3. Create a separate `Task` for each file.

   In the event handler, you would create a `Task` with a delegate that processes the file.

   This way, files will be processed in parallel.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that I had a very similar scenario I was working with and after reading your post I got myself an education on TPL Dataflow and successfully implemented the ActionBlock approach you recommended, greatly simplifying and streamlining my code.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `CollectionChanged` is a synchronous event. In a limited test app I wrote, I added a task to handle the change in a thread through a `ThreadFactory`.

My handle method looked something like this:

```
void threaded_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) {
            factory.StartNew(() => {
                object newSender = sender
                NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs newE = e;
                CollectionChanged(newSender, newE);
            });
        }
```

`factory`'s declaration: `TaskFactory factory = new TaskFactory();`. Always create a new reference to the parameters otherwise threads could receive the wrong ones.

Comment: “Always create a new reference to the parameters otherwise threads could receive the wrong ones.” Wrong. There are cases where copies like that are necessary (mostly in `foreach` before C# 5), but not here.